# GSM Modem is very slow. Sending 10 to 12 SMS Per Minutes

Tags: sms, sms-gateway

I am using nokia 5233 GSM Modem with SMS Caster. I want to send bulk SMS to my clients but my GSM Modem is very slow to do that. It is sending only 10 to 12 SMS Per minutes. I want to use my cell number and sim to send SMS but with very high speed. How cold I find an altrnate to my Cell's GSM Modem.

Comment: When you say that it's sending 10 to 12 sms per minute, if you exceed that number are the sms getting lost, or delayed?

Answer (score 4):

GSM Modems or phones are not designed for sending bulk messages at high rate. You will need to either get in touch with some bulk SMS providers or virtual-number providers that lets you do this. If you need a phone number to appear as sender-id in India, you will need to do this using a virtual number only.

Comment: I have seen few bulk sms provider using GSM modems, if not to use gsm modem which modem does bulk sending message service use ?

Comment: Then they must be GSM Routers, with multiple modems within. NowSMS gateway used to have free version allowing you to send unlimited number of SMS using modems. M not sure what's it like right now but you can give it a try. NowSMS will handle the queuing and load for you.

Comment: ok. Thank you. Is there any cdma routers ?

Answer (score 2):

I've been trying to send bulk messages via a GSM modem and found that the GSM network architecture makes  clients incapable of sending more than ~10 sms/minute or, allegedly, ~30 sms/minute using GPRS. Exact limits depend on the modem/device, provider and reception. To send more, as was suggested already, you need to look into a (paid) gateway service connected directly to a messaging centre.

Comment: When you say that it's sending about 10 sms per minute, if you exceed that number are the sms getting lost, or delayed?

Comment: @Matthew iirc I was using a serial connection to the GSM modem and sending sms by issuing `AT+CMGS` command which just blocked the connection until the message was sent

Answer (score 0):

i had experience sending 40000 sms at once. to do this contact gsm operators directly. they can send about 50 sms per second via direct connection to sms center. usualy they have web interface connected to sms center, have ways to provide basic data about people (gender, day of birth etc). You upload phone database to web interface and fire up your delivery. you get wholesale price for your delivery

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is true that GSM/GPRS modems cannot send messages at a high rate. You would need access to an SMS Centre or SMS Gateway as mentioned [here](http://www.developershome.com/sms/sms_tutorial.asp?page=smsc)!

Answer (score -1):

This is because of synchronous messaging model.
If you want to send 100 messages, only one thread will be executing this messaging sending activity.

In case you use `python` there is a multiprocessing  module
http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html.

There will be similar method in your programming language.

Comment: Not true - it is the design of GSM network that is the bottleneck. See my answer.